# Creating a list in Apex

Tags: apex, user, list, loop

I have made this list and its suppose to return all the users that are active but I dotn know why the for loop is wrong. do I need a Set?

```
public with sharing class ActiveAgents {

    public ActiveAgents() {
        User U = new User();
        List<User> ActiveUser = [SELECT Name , UserName, LastName
                                 FROM User
                                 WHERE IsActive = true];

        for (User currentUser : ActiveUser){


            U.add(currentUser.Name);
            U.add(currentUser.Username);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I want to get every single active user in a list, and then some how show it in an html page, I know I am suppose to make visual force page to do that @Bachovski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have your active users in a list by doing the following:

```
List<User> ActiveUser = [SELECT Name , UserName, LastName
                                 FROM User
                                 WHERE IsActive = true];
```

In order to display them on the page, you'll need to define a getter for your `ActiveUser` variable and make it public:

```
public with sharing class ActiveAgents {

    public List<User> ActiveUsers {get; private set;}

    public ActiveAgents() {
        User U = new User();
        ActiveUsers = [SELECT Name , UserName, LastName
                                 FROM User
                                 WHERE IsActive = true];
    }
}
```

Then in your page you can iterate through all the records in the list by using `apex:repeat`:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!ActiveUsers}" var="activeUser">
   <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Name}" />
   <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Username}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: That is great Thank you so much.  how come we dont need to use Iterator , like a for loop to go through one by one?  what if I want each department to show in diffferent column in the apex page?
also is this extra now User U = new User(); ?

Comment: The SOQL query by default returns a list of records hence you don't have to manually iterate through. If you need different columns, you'll need to query all columns for all the departments and then use the `rendered` attribute in your `outputText`. E.g. `<apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Username}" rendered="{!activeUser.Department__c == 'XYZ'}" />`

Comment: I see , Thank you so much . Quick question this gives me an error , is it wrong?'<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">

<apex:repeat value="{!ActiveUsers}" var="{!activeUser}">
   <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Name}" />
   <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Lastname}" />
   <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Username}" />
</apex:repeat>
 
</apex:page>' 
(agentList) Literal value is required for attribute var in <apex:repeat> in agentList at line 3 column 57

Comment: Change the `var="{!activeUser}"` to `var="activeUser"`. Apologies I wrote the answer on the fly and didn't test :)

Comment: I have no idea how you know so much, I wish I knew as much as you doooo :((( Thank you so much again

Comment: one more error question (agentList) Unknown property 'ActiveUsers' referenced in agentList  (Line: 1, Column: -1) this is for this <apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">

Comment: Ensure your variable name is the same in your apex controller, ensure it has a getter and it's public: `public List<User> ActiveUsers {get; private set;}`

Comment: Yah I have done it but its keep saying 
Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'

Comment: Problem solved, thank you so much . For some reason had the name of value same as var and didnt like it